# Init script still running after boot

Tags: bash, debian, scripting, systemd, init

I created a 1 line shell script to send me some custom notifications, and it works as intended. I placed the script in `/etc/init.d/`, ran `update-rc.d scan defaults`. After reboot, the notifier script is working properly. However `systemd-analyze blame` reports that the system is still booting for up to 5 minutes after I'm logged in, as the script is in tail reading a log file (and will never end unless terminated externally). How can I get this init script to finish "booting" earlier? Is there a cleaner way to do this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you get the script to fork?

Add a `&` to the line of code.

---

Look up job control in the bash manual, to find out more. Job control does a little more than a fork (if in an interactive shell).

Comment: Had no use for forking until now, thanks.